# Why does a file on an NFS mount seem to cache randomly, but no longer be cached when running `ls`?

Tags: linux, web-hosting, nfs, ls

Here's the mount configuration of an NFS mount, we'll call it **server2**, gotten from running `cat /etc/mtab`:

```
<ip1>:/mnt/fs101 /mnt/fs101 nfs rw,relatime,rsize=1024,wsize=1024,timeo=14,intr,cto,acregmax=6,acdirmax=0,noac,acdirmin=0,vers=4,addr=<ip1>,clientaddr=10.0.0.201 0 0
```

Another machine (call it **server1**) has more default settings, but is also mounting the NFS mount at . When I edit a file with `vim` on server1, and then run `cat file.txt`, I usually see the contents of the old file (i.e. not the edits).

If i type `ls -l` into the directory on **server2** (the one seeing the old contents), then run `cat` again, I now see the updated contents.

As you can see **server2** has its NFS caching effectively turned off. This affects across a number of machines, many (say 7 or 8) of which have this NFS mount attached. These are virtualized CentOS 6 machines running on VMWare.

I'm lost on where to go with this one—it seems it may be related to file attributes and to `ls` running stat on files but I'm not sure how I can effectively "fix" this issue. I'm okay with a certain period of caching for performance as these are webservers (10-20s) but right now it's completely unpredictable.

*Update:* when checking the machine that is presenting the NFS mount (i.e.  in above), this machine sees the updated file contents immediately after editing on server1